# Accessing context in RouteMapper

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to get `this.context` in the RouteMapper?
I am able to call `this.context.openMenu` in `Playground`.

I have the following:

```
class App extends Component {
    ...
    renderScene(route, navigator) {
        return (
            <Playground navigator={navigator} />
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Navigator
                ref="nav"
                renderScene={this._renderScene.bind(this)} />
        )
    }
} 
App.childContextTypes = {
    openMenu: React.PropTypes.func
}
```

This is Playground:

```
class Playground extends Component {
    ...
    render() {
        return (
            <Navigator
                renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
                navigator={this.props.navigator}
                navigationBar={
                    <Navigator.NavigationBar style={Styles.navBar}
                        routeMapper={PlaygroundMapper} />
            } />
        )
    }
}

Playground.contextTypes = {
    openMenu: React.PropTypes.func
}
```

Then PlaygroundMapper:

```
export default {
    LeftButton(route, navigator, index, navState) {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.context.openMenu}>
                <Text>Menu</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    },
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've reached this conclusion.

Since I have access to `this.context` in `Playground`, I did this:

```
<Navigator.NavigationBar
    style={Styles.navBar}
    routeMapper={ArticlesRouteMapper(this.context)} />
} />
```

Then in the RouteMapper, I did this:

```
export default (context) => ({
    LeftButton(route, navigator, index, navState) {
        return <Hamburger _onPress={() => context.openMenu()} />
    },
})
```

Works, but not sure if this is the proper way to do it.